# Given a dominant algebraically integral weight, how to construct all other weights and what are their multiplicities?

Tags: representation-theory, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ denote a complex semisimple Lie algebra. Fix a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $B(-,-)$ denote minus the Killing form on $\mathfrak{g}$ restricted to $\mathfrak{h}$. Let $\mathfrak{h}_0$ be the real span of the coroots of $\mathfrak{g}$ with respect to $B$. Note that $B(-,-)$ is positive definite on $\mathfrak{h}_0$. Choose a set $R_+ \subset \mathfrak{h}^*_0$ of positive roots of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Let $\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}^*_0$ be a dominant algebraically integral weight. Let $V$ be the corresponding finite-dimensional irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ corresponding to $\lambda$, which exists and is unique, up to isomorphism, by the highest weight theorem (please correct me if I am writing something wrong).

How can one find all weights of $V$ together with their multiplicities? There are some things that help of course. Given any $g \in W$, $g.\lambda$ is also a weight, with the same multiplicity as $\lambda$. By the way, does $\lambda$ always have multiplicity $1$? The difference between $2$ weights is an integral linear combination of roots.

So I am guessing that after forms the orbit $W.\lambda$, then one "fills" in the weights that are in the convex hull of $W.\lambda$ making sure that the difference between any two of the weights is an integral linear combination of the roots. Is this approach correct?

What about the multiplicities of each weight? I know that one can use Weyl's character formula for instance, but is there perhaps a more direct way?

Comment: I think (?) that the set of weights is the $\mathbb{R}$-convex hull of the orbbit $W \cdot \lambda$, intersected with the set $\{\mu \mid \mu \leq \lambda\}$. As for the multiplicities, as you noted there is Weyl's character formula, there is also Demazure's character formula, and there is also [Freudenthal's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_character_formula#Freudenthal's_formula) which is used by the LIE computer software, for example. When using Freudenthal's formula one would record only the multiplicities in the dominant chamber, working from the base case of the highest weight

Comment: @Joppy, thank you. What you wrote about the set of weights confirms my suspicion. Thank you for telling me about Freudenthal's formula!